# date format change in php to uk date

Tags: php, html

hi guys and girls looking to change the date to display in a uk format d/m/y code can be found below anyone got any ideas on how i can do this?

```
<style>

</style>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
<?php
include 'db-connect.php'; 

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM payments");

echo "
 <table border='0' align='center' text-align='left'>
<tr>
<th>Date To: <input></input></th>
<th>Date From: <input></input></th>
</tr>
</table>";

echo "<table border='0' align='center' text-align='left'>

<tr>
<th>Title:</th>
<th>Date:</th>
<th>Incoming:</th>
<th>Outgoing:</th>
<th>Notes:</th>
</tr>";

$totalIncoming = 0;
    $totalOutgoing = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      $totalIncoming += $row['incoming'];
      $totalOutgoing += $row['outgoing'];


      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td> £" . $row['incoming'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td> £" .  $row['outgoing'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['notes'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      }
    echo "</table>";
$profit = $totalIncoming - $totalOutgoing;
    echo "<div class='payment-total'><h1>Profit : £" . "$profit</h1></div>";


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

i really appricate anyone at all that can point me in the right direction or help me by giving me a line of code that will sort this! thanks in advance!

Comment: You may be new to StackOverflow. Please don't paste bunch of coding to your question, then readers may find it difficult to spot where the issue/problem is.

Answer (score 4):

I can't really see anything that has to do with date formatting in your code..

What is the format of the date you get currently from your database?

If it is a [string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), take a look at how to convert a date string into time [PHP strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [PHP Date Function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). This should help you.

Use this function:

```
$oldDate = "2003/03/24";
$newDate = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($oldDate));
```

This outputs `24/03/2003`

So in your code case it would be something like this:

`echo "<td>" . date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row['date'])) . "</td>";`

Comment: currently it displays in an y/m/d format when i want it in a d/m/y format. carnt seam to figure it out been trying for days

Comment: Side note on strtotime and the format of the date string, from the manual: Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (-), the date string is parsed as y-m-d.

To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

Answer (score 0):

use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) class

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime($row['date']);
echo $date->format('d-m-Y');
?>
```